# Change how Windows 10 Update Restarts

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, reboot

Is there a way to configure the update process for Windows 10 so that it does an in-place Kernel swap instead of rebooting?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: The only way to update the kernel on Windows is to perform a reboot.  What you want is absolutely not possible on Windows.

Comment: not "possible", not available, or not worth Window's time to fix? Isn't it possible outside of Windows?